# Where is the build path with Gradle

Tags: build-process, gradle

I want to use `Gradle` to  build the snapshot version for file-uploader https://github.com/valums/file-uploader .

My grade version is 1.4 and when I run `gradle zip` on `Mac OS X 10.7.5`, it shows `BUILD SUCCESSFUL`, but I can not where can I find the result file ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the project's build.gradle file:

```
task zip(type: Zip) {
    baseName "$filename-$version"
    from files("$buildDir")
    destinationDir file('release')
}
```

So the destination folder is called release, you'll find it under the project root.

Comment: Hi, there is no release folder, need I create one ?

Comment: no, it will be automatically created. looking at the build file again, you shouldn't run zip task rather createRelease